# How to Use Server Sent Events In Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to do some simple sse using my laravel 5.4 application. The difficulty am facing is actually from the server.

This is a controller method i have

Information controller class

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'country' => $request->get('country')
    ];

    $info = new Information($data); // My model
    $info->save();

    $push = new PushManager();
    $push->readPushValue($info); // intention here is to set the data to be sent as push. This doesnt seem to run.

    return response()->json(Information::find($info->id), 00);  
}
```

This is my PushManager.php class. NOTE: Not a controller

```
class PushManager
{
    public $data;

    public function readPushValue($data)
    {
        $this->data = data;
    }

    public function getPush()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

And finally this is my PushNotification controller

```
// all neccessary namespaces and use statements

    class PushNotification extends Controller
    {
        private function setupHeaders()
        {
            // headers for SSE
            header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');

            header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

            header('Connection: keep-alive');

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        }

        public function push()
        {
            $this->setupHeaders();

            $push = new PushManager();
            $data = $push->getPush(); // suppose to return the value setted in the Information controller

            echo "data: {$data}\n\n";
            flush();
        }
    }
```

I have a route that call the PushNotification controller push method 
Now any time my Information controller i.e the store method runs the `$push->readPushValue($data)` doesnt seem to work.

I know there is something wrong with the code and i hope you get what im trying to do. Please help.